# Remove first 3 posts of taxonomy from main query

Tags: wordpress, loops

I am trying to remove the first three posts of a taxonomy from the main query. I've run a whole bunch of ideas and examples from around the internet but none seem to be achieving what I need or just throw up errors. I believe it needs to utilize pre get posts, which I've got the code below for as far as I've got. It's not great but this has left me scratching my head and I can't seem to find any solutions out there.

```
function excluded( $query ) {
    if( $query->is_main_query() && ! is_admin() && $query->is_home() ) {
        $query->set( 'tag__not_in', '8384' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'excluded' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use the below code, By this, you can exclude the posts by their ids.

```
'post__not_in' => array('post_id_1','post_id_2','post_id_3');
```

Comment: I did go this route but could not seem to get the IDs from the taxonomy within the function. The few examples I found threw errors

Comment: Ended up putting me on the right track in the end, thank you

Answer (score 0):

This was the code that ended up working perfectly for me. If there is a less expensive method or more efficient way, would certainly be open to it

```
function excluded ( $query ) {
if( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_home() ) {
$removal = new WP_Query( array('posts_per_page' => 3,'tax_query' => array(array('taxonomy' => 'post_tag','field' => 'id','terms' => '1234' ))) );
if($removal){$those_ids = wp_list_pluck($removal->posts, 'ID');$query->set('post__not_in', $those_ids);}}}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'excluded' );
```